# Integrating Dojo with Django

Tags: javascript, django, dojo

I am creating a web app. Want to use django to handle backend - the data - and put Dojo on the front end for the interface. I new to a lot of this... and can't seem to find a straight-forward tutorial on HOW to integrate the two.

For starters: WHERE do you place the dojo.js script to "install" dojo to begin with?

Secondly: does anyone know of any good resources for working with these two? ANY advice or information would be extremely helpful. Thanks!!

~Heather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is server side code written in Python.

Dojo is client side code written in javascript, of course to get it to the clientside it needs to be part of your Django project, as a file. Alternatively you could refer to it using the dojo cdn.

You would refer to the file using a header tag in your html that looks like

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

I recommend getting started with Django, and loading up a page with some data. You can follow the many django tutorials available, including the [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/)

Once you have some pages loading, you can include the reference to dojo and start writing up some code using dojo. There are plenty of tutorials available for dojo, including the [official tutorials](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/#tutorials).

If you have a question about a part of django/dojo you should ask that question specifically.

Comment: Right, I've got Django set up, 3 or 4 apps created. It displays on it's own right now in Django admin. I'm trying to put Dojo on top of what I've got.

Answer (score 1):

[Dojango](https://github.com/klipstein/dojango/) a is project dedicated to Dojo integration with Django. This one is worth checking out.